# Move multiple files with unique name to new folder and append to file name

Tags: linux, batch-rename, mv

I have about 2000 files in a folder.

All the files contain the string `test` in the name.

What I need to do is move all those files ~1250 to a folder called `trash` within the same directory and append `_scrap` to the end of each file.

```
 mv *test* trash/
```

What I want is something like this:

```
[root@server] ls
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt trash  video1.txt  video2.txt  video3.txt
[root@server] mv *test* trash/*_scrap
[root@server] ls
trash  vidoe1.txt  video2.txt  video3.txt
[root@server] ls trash/
test1.txt_scrap  test2.txt_scrap  test3.txt_scrap
```

I can move all files, however I cannot figure out how to append the `_scrap` to the end.

As I have to do this on a number of machines, a one liner would be preferable over a small script.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ touch test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt vidoe1.txt  vidoe2.txt  vidoe3.txt
$ mkdir trash
$ for file in *test*; do mv "$file" "trash/${file}_scrap"; done
$ ls
trash       vidoe1.txt  vidoe2.txt  vidoe3.txt
$ ls trash
test1.txt_scrap test2.txt_scrap test3.txt_scrap
$
```

You could also use `xargs`

```
$ ls *test* | xargs -t -I{} mv {} trash/{}_scrap
mv test1.txt trash/test1.txt_scrap
mv test2.txt trash/test2.txt_scrap
mv test3.txt trash/test3.txt_scrap
$
```

You could use `find`

```
$ find . -name '*test*' -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} trash/{}_scrap \;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename` to avoid shell for loops.  It's a perl script but it comes installed with many common distros (including Ubuntu 14):

```
$ mv *test* trash/
$ rename 's/$/_scrap/g' trash/*
$ ls trash/
test1.txt_scrap  test3.txt_scrap  test2.txt_scrap
```

Comment: Trick: `mkdir z; mv *; mv z trash;` moves all the files in to the directory.  Note that if some files start with `z`, the directory will need to be named `zz` (or `zzz` - the directory needs to be the last item on the `*` expansion).